# В обоих ли похожих предложениях нужна запятая?

Tags: пунктуация

Он сказал, что войны на Земле когда-нибудь прекратятся (?) и все люди доброй воли должны бороться за мир.
"Войны на Земле когда-нибудь прекратятся (?) и все люди доброй воли должны бороться за мир", - сказал он.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В первом примере запятая не нужна,т.к между однородными придаточными частями сложноподчиненного предложения, связанными неповторяющимися союзами (соединительными или разделительными) запятая не ставится. Ср. ***Отец мой говорил, что он не видывал таких хлебов и что нынешний год урожай отличный (Акс.);***

Во втором примере запятая нужна, союз и соединяет части сложного предложения.

См. [Справочник по пунктуации. Розенталь. Д.Э.](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=139#pp139)

Comment: Спасибо, Серж !